# I want to calculate how many friends a user has, but I don't know how to

Tags: stata

Please apologize for the title, I don't know how I can otherwise formulate that!

So I have here a dataset from steam which includes `steamid` = individual user on steam, and `steamid_b` = another user which is a friend of this. Now I want to calculate how many friends each `steamid` has.

Here is a sample from my dataset:

```
steamid             steamid_b
76561197960265729   76561197967144365
76561197960265730   *76561197960265733*
76561197960265730   *76561197960265733*
76561197960265730   *76561197960265733*
*76561197960265733* 76561197964770089
*76561197960265733* 76561197964770089
*76561197960265733* 76561197964770089
*76561197960265733* 76561197964770089
*76561197960265733* 76561197964770089
76561197960265738   76561198010062752
76561197960265738   76561198010062752
76561197960265738   76561198010062752
76561197960265742   76561197960268662
76561197960265742   76561197960268662
76561197960265742   76561197960268662
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265743   76561197992910264
76561197960265744   76561197968452293
76561197960265745   76561197962688722
```

It looks for the first time as if every user has only one friend, but we can see that `steamid` also sometimes appears as `steamid_b` so it means he/she has actually 2 friends. For example, `76561197960265733` has the friend `76561197964770089` but he/she also appears as friend of `76561197960265730` so `76561197960265733` actually has 2 friends. Which command can I use to caculate such relationships? I don't if it is relevant, but the dataset has over 32 million observations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each observation represents a friend relationship, I would simply count the number of unique observations:

```
duplicates drop, force

preserve
keep steamid
tempfile id
save `id'
restore

keep steamid_b
rename steamid_b steamid
append using `id'

by steamid: gen count = _N
```

I have not tested this. You could also create a dummy that equals 1 and collapse (sum) by steamid to get a count of friends:

```
duplicates drop, force

preserve
keep steamid
tempfile id
save `id'
restore

keep steamid_b
rename steamid_b steamid
append using `id'

gen count = 1
collapse (sum) count, by(steamid)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Each row represents actually for one game which the user has. I have already solved this problem. But still, thank you very much!